# Преобразование проблемного обьекта в json

Tags: java, json, rest

Суть проблемы в том что бы ответ получить в json.

есть мой restTemplate

```
restTemplate.exchange(endpoint, HttpMethod.GET, null, String.class);
```

пока преобразовываю в строку, так как в обьект затруднительно из-за одинаковых "ключей"

прилетает ответ такого формата:

```
["CN=MegaUsers,OU=Office,OU=Пользователи,DC=bank,DC=ua",
        "CN=InetEnterprise,OU=Groups,OU=UsersGroups,DC=bank,DC=ua"]
```

в конечном итоге необходимо получить

```
[{"CN":"MegaUsers","OU":"Office","OU":"Пользователи", "DC":"bank", "DC":"ua"},
{"CN":"InetEnterprise","OU":"Groups","OU":"UsersGroups", "DC":"bank", "DC":"ua"}]
```

масив псевдообьектов может быть любой, от 1 и до...

какие есть варианты решения преобразовать в json?

Comment: а есть причина по которой вы не хотите писать для `"OU"` и `"DC"` json-массивы значений?

Comment: Думал, но стоит задача вернуть именно такой json-массив

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Возможно есть более изящное решение, библиотека например?

```
    String replace = s.replace("[\"", "").replace("\"]", "");
    String[] split = replace.split("\",\"");
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append("[");
    for(int j = 0; j < split.length; j++) {
        String[] split1 = split[j].split(",");
        sb.append("{");
        for(int i = 0; i < split1.length; i++) {
            String repl = split1[i].replace("=", "\":\"");
            sb.append("\"").append(repl).append("\"");
            if (split1.length - 1 != i) {
                sb.append(",");
            }
        }
        sb.append("}");
        if (split.length - 1 != j) {
            sb.append(",");
        }
    }
    sb.append("]");
    System.out.println(sb.toString());
}
```